# plotting users and their visits by date

Tags: r

I have a data set with nearly 1Mn records of Users and their visit on an App by date. There are two columns, one with user Id's and the other having the date on which the user has visited on the app. Each row is a unique combination of User and Date. Now I want to know for all the users who came on the App on day1, how have they been visiting the App in a month and similarly for all the users who came on 2,3,4 and so on.

Is it possible to draw a graph to show how these users have visited on the platform starting from Day1.

Data looks like this.

```
x=sprintf("M_%03d", 1:25)
y=seq(as.Date('2011-01-01'),as.Date('2011-01-31'),by = 1)
dat = expand.grid(x = x, y = y)
dat2 = data.frame( ID = sample( dat$x , nrow( dat ) ) , Score = sample( 
dat$y , nrow( dat ) ) )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you check out [these links](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+r+cohort), try some things out, and come back with a meaningful reproducible example (>1 month of data for a few users?).

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider approaching this by constructing a factor tag indicating which week (or day) a particular user started using the service.

First, tag each User ID with the date they joined:

```
require(dplyr)

dat3 <- dat2 %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(JoinDate = min(Score))
```

Calculate the earliest date:

```
start_Date <- min(dat3$Score))
```

Tag each row with the day the user first visited:

```
dat3 <- dat3 %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(DaysSince = difftime(JoinDate, start_Date, units="days"))
```

Convert to factor for plotting so we can use it as a categorical tag.

```
dat3$DaysSince <- as.factor(dat3$DaysSince)
```

Graph using ggplot. Using `geom_jitter()` to avoid overlapping points where users visited multiple times per day.

There are a lot of ways you might visualize something like this, but here's one approach. You might also try a heat map.

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat3, aes(DaysSince,Score, color=DaysSince)) +geom_point()+geom_jitter()+coord_flip()
```

[image]